# Open iFrame links in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have endlessly tried to open iframe links inside either the parent tab or a new tab however I just can't seem to get them to work. When I set the links to target="_parent" the links do nothing and when I set the links to target="_blank" they open in a new tab but also display nothing.

As soon as I get rid of the code that adds the target to the links they work but open inside the iframe which is not what I am trying to accomplish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the iframe code that I am using:

```
<iframe src="js/eventsFrame2.php?EventID=2422308" id="frameclass" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="600">
```

Here is the code inside the iframe:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    $("a").attr('target','_parent');

  }
$(window).load(myFunction);

</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    document.write('<script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1761&amp;sitenumber=18&amp;tid=ticket_results&amp;evtid=2422308"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: The same origin policy dictates that you can't access contents within the iframe, is what you're seeing here not just the reverse of that? I'm not sure. +1 anyway.

Comment: @DeeMac Is it possible to open links from an iframe in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the content inside the iframe, you could try using the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag.

Example -- In the page loaded into the iframe include a base tag within the head:

```
<base target="_top"/>
```

Comment: I do have control of the content inside the iframe however the base tag does the same thing as giving the links a target so it doesn't work. When I add a base tag the links don't return anything.

Comment: @eric212 I put together a quick and dirty test here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34718810/stackoverflow/iframe-test.html Does this not accomplish what you are looking to do?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. However the base does not work for some reason when I add it to my code.

Comment: Are you still adding target attributes in your javascript?

Comment: Not when I put the base tag in, I comment them out

Comment: Sure the code looks like this `<base target="_top" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 document.write('<script language="javascript" src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1761&amp;sitenumber=18&amp;tid=ticket_results&amp;evtid=2422308"><\/script>');
</script>`

Comment: Where is the link that you are trying to click on come from?  Is the above code added in the <head> element of the iframe page?

Comment: No, the javascript is put into the body tag and it displays the links which I am getting from ticket network.

Comment: Have you tried moving the base tag to the head? <head><base target='_top'/></head><body><!--js--></body>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overwriting the parent page (containing the iframe) with your content?

Code inside the iframe:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    parent.document.write('<script src="http://tickettransaction.com/?bid=1761&amp;sitenumber=18&amp;tid=ticket_results&amp;evtid=2422308"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: That could work however I would only want the iframe to overwrite the content of the parent page once a user clicks on a link. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible... For that to happen you'd need to redirect the **response, and not the action for the click,** to the parent page.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could redirect the response?

Answer (score 0):

Query defines the [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to grab the document node, but it doesn't give you a cross-browser way to go from the document to the window, so you're still stuck with:

```
var iframea = $('iframe').contents().find("a");

iframea.attr('target','_parent');
```

IMPORTANT: you should always check that the document is with the status "complete" for work with this

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('iframe_id');
//var iframewindow= iframe.contentWindow
//? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
if (preview.readyState=="complete")
{
   //ok
}
else
{
   //perform a recursive call until it is complete
}
```

Comment: Avril, thanks for the response. I added your first code above the iframe however it still did not work. The links opened inside of the iframe did not open in the parent tab they still opened in the iframe.